Can Python TypeAliases or Annotated objects be used in generics?
Consider the following:
import pydantic

def buildTypeAdapter[T](cls: type[T]) -> pydantic.TypeAdapter[T]:
    return pydantic.TypeAdapter(cls)

ta1 = buildTypeAdapter(list[str]) # GOOD: pyright sees this as a TypeAdapter[list[str]]
out1 = ta1.validate_python(None)  # GOOD: pyright sees this as a list[str]


Now, compare to the following:
type ListOfStrings = list[str]
ta2 = buildTypeAdapter(ListOfStrings)
out2 = ta2.validate_python(None)

This one fails to validate:
error: Argument of type "ListOfStrings" cannot be assigned to parameter "cls" of type "type[T@buildTypeAdapter]" in function "buildTypeAdapter"
    Type "TypeAliasType" is incompatible with type "type[T@buildTypeAdapter]" (reportArgumentType)

...and it sees ta2 as being of type TypeAdapter[Unknown], and out2 being Unknown.

A similar problem exists with:
ta3 = buildTypeAdapter(Annotated[list[str], "Testing"])

where pyright reports:
error: Argument of type "type[Annotated]" cannot be assigned to parameter "cls" of type "type[T@buildTypeAdapter]" in function "buildTypeAdapter"

...and accordingly treats the object as a TypeAdapter[Unknown]. (Incidentally, ta3 = pydantic.TypeAdapter(Annotated[list[str], "Foobar"]) itself is also seen as a TypeAdapter[Unknown], even though it doesn't throw an error about failing to meet the calling signature).

I've tried something like:
def buildTypeAdapter[T](cls: Annotated[T, ...]) -> pydantic.TypeAdapter[T]:
    return pydantic.TypeAdapter(cls)

or
def buildTypeAdapter[T](cls: TypeAliasType[T]) -> pydantic.TypeAdapter[T]:
    return pydantic.TypeAdapter(cls)

but these aren't supported. Are there equivalents that function as desired?

(Note that Pydantic is used here as an example that's ready-at-hand and widely familiar, but the question isn't intended to be about it as such. The focus, rather, is intended to be on giving type information to static checkers for Python -- and pyright in particular -- that "reaches into" type aliases and annotations when describing the relationship between arguments and return types).

Seems like a bug in the checker for the annotated case. Using mypy and an extra statement, I get the expected results. v = Annotated[list[str], "Testing"]; r = buildTypeAdapter(v); typing.reveal_type(r) -> Revealed type is "pydantic.type_adapter.TypeAdapter[builtins.list[builtins.str]]"

Duplicate: How to type annotate optional class type param. I'm sure I have seen a better one; I'll try to find it.

Quick explanation in the mean while: Pyright is correct that Annotated[...] is not assignable to type[T], because the latter only accepts concrete classes (even though the former is callable). To quote: "However, the actual argument passed in at runtime must still be a concrete class object [...]".

(The spec is unclear about this, though, so Mypy isn't exactly wrong.)

I'm exceedingly glad to see typing_extensions.TypeForm in https://github.com/python/typing_extensions/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md, even if it hasn't made it out to a release yet. Thank you for linking the proposed duplicate -- it's immensely helpful!
